# Unknown Segmentation fault Error while incrementing the index value in 2d array

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, nested-loops

There "Segmentation fault" error in the code.

```
int hourglassSum(int arr_rows, int arr_columns, int** arr) {
    int sum=0,max=0;
    for(int i=0; i<arr_columns;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<arr_rows;j++){
            sum = arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2];
            if(sum>max){
                max = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I have done some debugging and I found that whenever I increment the 'i' that is 'i+1' and 'i+2' the error occurs.
`arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2];`

This is the error

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040135a in hourglassSum (arr_rows=6, 
    arr_columns=<optimized out>, arr=<optimized out>) at Solution.c:33
33              if(sum>max){
```

Comment: Well your indexes are obviously out of range - there's not enough context here to speculate why that is.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this statement

```
sum = arr[i][j]+arr[i][j+1]+arr[i][j+2]+arr[i+1][j+1]+arr[i+2][j]+arr[i+2][j+1]+arr[i+2][j+2];
```

when `i` is equal to at least `arr_columns - 2` and `j` is equal to at least  `arr_rows - 2` there is an access outside the arrays in expressions like  `arr[i+2][j]` and `arr[i][j+2]` because the valid ranges of indices are `[0, arr_rows )` and `[0, arr_columns )`.

What you do is what you get.

Also as the arrays are of the signed type `int` then the initial value of the variable `max` is incorrect

```
int sum=0,max=0;
```

The arrays for example can have all negative elements.

Also if you indeed are passing to the function a two-dimensional array instead of an array of arrays then this parameter declaration

```
int** arr
```

is incorrect.

In this case the function should be declared like

```
int hourglassSum(int arr_rows, int arr_columns, int arr[][arr_columns]);
```